# Unable to open iterator for alias while using CONCAT

Tags: apache-pig

Trying to split a column from originaldata and need to join back.
For that I created a rowid along with originaldata and seperated a col from originaldata along with concatenating the rowid

```
originaldata = load '$input' using PigStorage('$delimiter');
rankedoriginaldata = rank originaldata;
numericdata = foreach rankedoriginaldata generate CONCAT($0,$split);
```

But I am not able to do this statement

```
numericdata = foreach rankedoriginaldata generate CONCAT($0,$split);
```

Command

```
pig -x local -f seperator.pig -param input=data/StringNum.csv -param output=OUT/Numericfile -param delimiter="," -param split='$3'
```

It shows the following stack tree

```
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias numericdata

org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias numericdata
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:838)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processDump(GruntParser.java:696)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:320)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:194)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:170)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:475)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:208)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Job terminated with anomalous status FAILED
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.openIterator(PigServer.java:830)
    ... 12 more
================================================================================
```

But when I did

```
numericdata = foreach originaldata generate CONCAT($0,$split);
```

I am getting the expected output.

**Doubt**: While loading a data do the order of tuple change?
If we are loading a data say

```
1,4,6
3,8,9
2,4,5
```

How will be the ordering
whether it shuffles like

```
1,6,4
8,9,3...
```

Comment: i am giving a field as an argument,ie if i am giving $3 then i will get 4 th field of tuple. CONCAT($0,$3)

Comment: For people who found this post when looking for [ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495085/error-1066-unable-to-open-iterator-for-alias-in-pig-generic-solution) here is a [generic solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34495086/983722).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try casting your arguments for `CONCAT` to chararray first:

```
numericdata = foreach originaldata generate CONCAT((chararray)$0,(chararray)$split);
```

I think the cast is necessary because `CONCAT` expects two chararrays. `RANK` however produces a Long (which you pass as $0 to `CONCAT`).

Concerning your doubt: order of fields in your tuples is not going to change. The order of tuples in the relation may change however.

Comment: Yes Fred Thanks it works.Why we need to cast?What about the doubt i mentioned in question?

Comment: I am using Pig version 0.11.0-cdh4.6.0.So I am able to do multiple concat.CONCAT($0,\t,$3).For that should I covert it tochararray.

Comment: Sorry I did nt get U.The order of tuples in the relation may change however.means?

Comment: if you have a relation with tuples
`a1,a2\r\n
b1,b2\r\n
c1,c2`
you cannot be sure to see the lines in the same order. The order of the fields within each line will not change.

Comment: That means lines can shuffle.But not shuffling between fields .Am I right?If any operation done to the bag can change the order,Am I right?